# HP Probook 4540s WiFi and Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 12.04lts

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, bluetooth

I am facing a issue after install Ubuntu 12.04LTS on My laptop (hp Probook 4540s).
My wireless LAN and Bluetooth is not working.
I got a list after put this command in terminal:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(wireless|network)"
```

Result:

```
Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2860
    Kernel modules: rt3290sta
```

I am not a expert in Ubuntu.So kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial solution!  This is based on https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms

This will install a compatible driver:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms
sudo modprobe rtbth
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`

With that, I'm able to scan for Bluetooth devices and connect to them. Sadly, I can't get it to transfer data!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Fixed it by removing the Ralink wifi card and replacing it with an Atheros card from a scrap Laptop.
Now all works great in Linux, Backtrack and Win7
BikerMike

Comment: please provide more detail so the poster can reproduce the steps you took to correct the issue.