# Bluetooth is not working on hp probook 4540s for several ubuntu versions

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth, hp

I have an HP probook 4540s laptop that has Ubuntu 18.04.1lts and I can't make bluetooth work I also had ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 before and also bluetooth didn't work, I tried also the solution in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300964/hp-probook-4540s-wifi-and-bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-12-04lts) and executed these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms
sudo modprobe rtbth
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

but it just made the bluetooth button active with no effect.
Note that when I executed `sudo lshw | grep Bluetooth` I found my bluetooth driver is RT3290 and I know there is an issue with that drive, so this could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying the [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778615/ralink-rt-3290-bluetooth-problem-on-ubuntu-16-04) and then executing the commands in [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300964/hp-probook-4540s-wifi-and-bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-12-04lts), that kinda solved the problem for me, I just still have a problem with deactivating and re-activating bluetooth.
The steps for the solution are:

1. Download and install the RT3290 driver

   `sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
   mkdir ~/tmp
   cd ~/tmp
   git clone https://github.com/loimu/rtbth-dkms.git
   cd rtbth-dkms/
   make
   sudo make install
   sudo cp -r ./ /usr/src/rtbth-3.9.3
   sudo dkms install rtbth/3.9.3
   sudo nano /etc/modules`
2. > Add `rtbth` at the end, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (to save the file) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to close the editor
3. Reboot

"Until this point I still couldn't activate bluetooth".

4. Execute these commands

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:blaze/rtbth-dkms
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install rtbth-dkms
   sudo modprobe rtbth
   sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
   ```

And with this I can scan for devices, send and receive files regularly.

--EDIT--

5. I found a solution for reactivating Bluetooth on startup (based on solution of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup)).

   As /etc/rc.local doesn't exist for Ubuntu 18.04

   > you'll need to create one and make it executable. To make things slightly easier, you can just paste the following command into a terminal:

   ```
   sudo install -b -m 755 /dev/stdin /etc/rc.local << EOF
   #!/bin/sh
   modprobe rtbth
   rfkill unblock bluetooth
   exit 0
   EOF
   ```

This creates /etc/rc.local file and put in it the previous commands and executes every startup, just don't turn bluetooth off.

Comment: I think if you do `sudo depmod -a` you could skip the step of adding rtbth to /etc/modules